# Ansible keeps complaining about the public_ip not defined , which is already an attribute in ec2 items registered

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I have been trying to apply simple playbook to spin up ec2 instance and trying to fetch the public_ip of the instance and edit the hosts file so next in line playbook can be executed on that instance. but every time i add items.public_ip it throws not defined error . Am i missing something?

```
>     fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    >         "failed": true, 
    >         "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was:
    'unicode
    > object' has no attribute 'public_ip'\n\nThe error appears to have been
    > in <some path>  line 76, column 9, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file
    > depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears
    > to be:\n\n\n      - name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the
    > local host group (located inside the directory)\n        ^ here\n"
    >     }
```

my debug ec2 item does show the public ip in the list.

```
- name: Debug
        debug:
          msg: "{{ ec2 }}"
```

My Task section :

```
 - name: Add the newly created EC2 instance(s) to the local host group (located inside the directory)
    local_action: lineinfile
                  dest="./hosts"
                  regexp="{{ item.public_ip }}"
                  insertafter="[vm]" line="{{ item.public_ip }}"
    with_items: ec2_instances
```

Any help would be helpful !!

Comment: Even though i tried direct approaches to provide these public_dns_name and id in vars but no luck , json for ec2 although provides all details...not sure why it's not picking up ..:(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Ansible's set\_fact and with\_item on a list of maps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33980776/how-to-use-ansibles-set-fact-and-with-item-on-a-list-of-maps)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out the answer by providing vpc_subnet_id along with public_ip attributes defined in the ec2 module so it can be used further tasks in  playbooks. I think the network interface attribute can be made mandatory to get the actual use of ec2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   - name: Check ec2_public_ip
     command: curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
     register: ec2_public_ip
```

Reference:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html