# How to change a dict variable in ansible

Tags: ansible

I would like to add a dict variable when looping with `with_items` like this:

```
set_fact:
  item.template: "base"
  when: item.template is not defined
  with_items: vHosts
```

But it seems to write to an wrong dictionary, i have then `{"ansible_facts": {"item.template": "base"}, "item": {...}}`.

trying `vHosts['item']['template']` doesn't work either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using set\_facts and with\_items together in Ansible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399581/using-set-facts-and-with-items-together-in-ansible)

Comment: Seems so. Ansible has some rather strange semantics -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like this behaviour is not (yet) possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/29419080/893159.

My current workaround is now just to run one loop `when: item.template is not defined` and one `when item.template is defined` in the next statements, using `item.template` in one and using `"base"` in another.