# Ansible - Get groups specific subgroups

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have the following groups defined in my inventory:

```
[webservers]

[server_storage]

[server_ws1]

[webservers:children]
server_storage
server_ws1
```

During my play, I'm in need of getting the names of the children groups of group['webservers'] ONLY (I think of theese as 'subgroups')

So, let's say I would need to set_fact a variable that contains in this case, the list of strings:

```
 - server_storage
 - server_ws1
```

This would have to be dynamic, so if I add group 'server_ws2' to group['webservers'], this should return

```
 - server_storage
 - server_ws1
 - server_ws2
```

I've been playing with the use of group_names, group['webservers'] (which doesn't return subgroups, but hostnames)

Basically, I need a simple way of getting a the list of subgroups of a specific group. Is this possible without the use of black magic?

**UPDATE**: The idea, is that the hosts could belong to more groups, but I need only the subgroups or children of webservers group. It's constant, no matter the host, the output should allways be the same.

By the way, this one didn't work [How can I get a list of child groups in Ansible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39655419/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-child-groups-in-ansible), because it retuns all groups for the current host, I need only subgroups of the specified group.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Get the names of the children groups of group['webservers']"*

A: For example, the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
[webservers]

[server_storage]
host_01

[server_ws1]
host_02

[webservers:children]
server_storage
server_ws1
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: webservers
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        subgroups: "{{ subgroups|default([]) + hostvars[item].group_names }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.webservers }}"
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ subgroups|unique|difference(['webservers']) }}"
      run_once: true
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml 

  msg:
  - server_storage
  - server_ws1
```

---

As a workaround, it's possible to use `ansible-inventory` to list the structure of the inventory, store the output in a file, and use this file as needed, e.g. [*include_vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task) in a playbook. See the example below

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host_01
host_02

[webservers]

[server_storage]

[server_ws1]

[webservers:children]
server_storage
server_ws1
```

```yaml
shell> ansible-inventory -i hosts --list --output hosts.json
shell> cat hosts.json
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {}
    },
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped",
            "webservers"
        ]
    },
    "ungrouped": {
        "hosts": [
            "host_01",
            "host_02"
        ]
    },
    "webservers": {
        "children": [
            "server_storage",
            "server_ws1"
        ]
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it does not work as intended. I'll update de question with the problem. Your answer works only if those hosts belong only to those groups, but if they belong to additional groups, those show up as well with your code.

Comment: Ansible does not collect any information about the group's structure. Only `hostvars[item].group_names` is available. As a result: 1) It's not possible to analyze the structure of empty groups from a playbook. 2) It's possible to intersect/difference flat lists of the groups only.

Comment: I understand, seems like there's no simple way of achieving what I need, (the reason of actually needing this is a long story, it's not a whim, so far couldn't find a way to re-structure some things on my current setup to  make this become unnecesary).
I had a feeling this was going to be the case, hence the "black magic" comment. Thank you for the effort though.
I'll keep this open for a while and see If someone comes up with a workaround, and if nothing happens, mark your answer as the correct one.
Thanks.

Comment: As a workaround, try `ansible-inventory`. I've updated the answer with an example.