# Ansible loop through a set of dicts, register that list and then print the specific output

Tags: ansible

Here is what I am trying to do.

> 1. log onto a networking switch using the built in networking modules and send a command.
> 2. register that command as a var
> 3. print that var or use that var elsewhere inside of a playbook.

This seems simple right? But here are the issues I am facing.

First of all, I am logging into one device (currently) and then issuing a simple command inside of a loop (this becomes 2 commands, and 2 outputs).

I want to put the outputs from both of the commands into a list.
Next I would like to loop through this list and inspect the return of the value from each command (remember this is 2 outputs).

Here is the current play:

```
- name: Checking for free ports
  nxos_command: 
    provider: 
      host: "{{inventory_hostname}}" 
      username: "{{user.stdout}}"
    commands: "show run interface {{ item.interface }}"
  when: device.ansible_facts.ansible_device_os == 'nxos' 
  loop: "{{ device_vars[inventory_hostname] }}"
  register: ports
```

Then when I use debug, I get a bunch of data:

```
- debug: 
    var: item.stdout
  loop: "{{ports.results}}"
  register: ports_output
```

I then set the fact and then debug (print) once more:

```
- name: Setting var
  set_fact: 
    port_list: "{{item.stdout}}"
  loop: "{{ports.results}}"

- debug: var=port_list
```

The problem I am getting is that even though `port_list` is a list, ansible is only returning one value of that list. This is the last value/command from the initial play. So I am assuming it is being overwritten somewhere.

Here would be my desired output:

```
ok: [device1] => {
    "port_list": [
        "1st output from the device",
        "2nd output from the device"
    ]
}
```

But all I can get is this:

```
ok: [device1] => {
    "port_list": [
        "2nd output from the device"
    ]
}
```

Here is are the vars I am declaring inside of my `site.yml`:

```
  vars:
    device_vars:
      device1:                                                                 
      - interface: Ethernet1/1
        description: "some description
        vlan: 1
      - interface: Ethernet1/2
        description: "some description"
        vlan: 1
    port_list: []
```

I think my issue here is I am working with a dict of dicts of lists etc. and it doesn't seem that Ansible is very friendly with this.
I've managed to get the data into this format (omitted):

```
{
"ports": 
    {
    "results": 
        [
            {
              "stdout": 
                [
                  "1st output from the device"
                ]
            },
            {
              "stdout":
                [
                  "2nd output from the device"
                ]
            } 
        ]
    }
}
```

I've spent 3 days on this and can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: I ended up using this:
`port_list: "{{ port_list|default([]) + item.stdout }}"`
As I didn't want a list of lists, just one list - thanks all!

Edit: This is different from the dupe, as I am managing `with_lists` and not `with_items` which is different. Also the data is coming from ansible output and not user defined.

Comment: If it is different, then why the duplicate target contains [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47256856/2947502) as you accepted? And if it was different enough for you to claim that, then why did you accept this wrong answer in the first place?　Duplicate target question is a clear-cut duplicate of yours and it also contains a better solution, you just need to use `map(attribute='stdout.0')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

During the loop `set_fact` overwrites the variable, therefore you just see the last variable is being set. However you can also use `set_fact` to  append the the previously assigned value and include all of variables as follows:

```
- name: Setting var
  set_fact: 
    port_list: "{{ port_list|default([]) + [item.stdout] }}"
  loop: "{{ports.results}}"
```

`default([])` filter above is to assign an initial value to `port_list` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Append the elements to the list

```
port_list: "{{ port_list + [item.stdout] }}"
```